# set xlim in ggplot2 using numericRangeInput in R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to control the xlim using numericrangeInput. Initial values are set as c(NA,NA).

If I try to change the scale min and max values and before updating one of the values it throws error **Missing values ​​cannot be used where TRUE/FALSE values ​​are required**

Any suggestions to fix this error.

Below is the code

```
      library(shiny)
      library(tidyverse)

      data <- faithful %>% mutate(eruptionTime=lubridate::now() + lubridate::dhours(cumsum(waiting)))

      ui <- fluidPage(
             numericRangeInput(inputId = "noui1", label = "Numeric Range Input:",
             value = c(NA, NA)
             ),  
            plotOutput("plot9")
            )

      server <- function(input, output) {


           output$plot9 <- renderPlot({

           print(paste("What is the condition",!anyNA(input$noui1))) 
   
           iris %>%ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) +
           coord_cartesian(xlim=input$noui1)

          })
          }

     shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the plot only after you input both the numbers in `numericRangeInput`.

Try this code -

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

data <- faithful %>% mutate(eruptionTime=lubridate::now() + lubridate::dhours(cumsum(waiting)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericRangeInput(inputId = "noui1", label = "Numeric Range Input:",
                    value = c(NA, NA)
  ),  
  plotOutput("plot9")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
  output$plot9 <- renderPlot({
    plot <- iris %>%ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length))
    
    if(length(input$noui1) == 2)
      plot <- plot + coord_cartesian(xlim=input$noui1)
    plot
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```